# Is it possible to search all the objects in all the databases in Teradata?

Tags: teradata

I have multiple databases in Teradata, and each database has many objects. I want to search for a particular table by its name, but I don't remember the database name. Is it possible to search for a table by its name in all the databases?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM dbc.TablesV WHERE TableKind = 'T' AND TableName = 'xxx'`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you write it as an answer, so that I can accept it as a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access Teradata's [Data Dictionary](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/Database_Management/B035_1092_151K/title.014.2.html)  which is owned by user `dbc`.

```
SELECT * FROM dbc.TablesV 
WHERE TableKind = 'T'  -- only Tables
  AND TableName = 'xxx'
```

The name `TablesV` is misleading as it also contains info about Views ( `TableKind = 'V'`, Procedures (`'V'`), etc.

There are similar tables for databases/users (`dbc.DatabasesV`), columns (`dbc.ColumnsV`), Indexes (`dbc.IndicesV`), etc.